# Elasticsearch Fuzzy Phrases

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following query to add fuzziness to my search. However, I now realize that the match query doesn't consider the order of the words in the search string, as the match_phrase does. However, I can't get match_phrase to give me results with fuzziness. Is there a way to tell match to consider the order and distance between words?

```
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "content": {
                "query": "some search terms like this",
                "fuzziness": 1,
                "operator": "and"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Eventually figured out that I needed to use a combination of `span` queries, which give an excellent amount of fine tuning to fuzziness and slop. I needed to add a function to manually tokenize my phrases and add to the "clauses" array in an programmatically:

```
{"query":
{
  "span_near": {
    "clauses": [
      {
        "span_multi": {
          "match": {
            "fuzzy": {
              "content": {
                "fuzziness": "2",
                "value": "word"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "span_multi": {
          "match": {
            "fuzzy": {
              "content": {
                "fuzziness": "2",
                "value": "another"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }                   
    ],
    "slop": 1,
    "in_order": "true"
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, it worked for me, but I think I should mention that the `content` should be replaced with the `field_name` that you want to search. For instance, if you want to search the `title` field, then replace `"content": {"fuziness": "2", "value": "word"}` with `"title": {"fuziness": "2", "value": "word"}`.

Comment: I wish there were a way for elasticsearch to tokenize the phrases and then pass them into this span_near clause. Is there a way?

Comment: @GNG may be you could make one extra request https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-tokenizer.html preceding this one. And then programmatically build request with span_near.

Answer (score 2):

@econgineer Excellent post.

I wanted to try this for an ES query we are working on - but I am too lazy to keep doing the JSON data....

I think this code works... strangely it causes jq to complain but ElasticSearch work....

```
import json
import pprint
from collections import defaultdict
nested_dict = lambda: defaultdict(nested_dict)
query=nested_dict()
query['span_near']['clauses']=list()
query['slop']='1'
query['in_order']="true"


words=['what','is','this']
for w in words:
    nest = nested_dict()
    nest["span_multi"]["match"]["fuzzy"]["msg"]["fuzziness"]["value"]=w
    nest["span_multi"]["match"]["fuzzy"]["msg"]["fuzziness"]["fuzziness"]="2"
    json.dumps(nest)
    query['span_near']['clauses'].append(json.loads(json.dumps(nest)))


pprint.pprint(json.loads(json.dumps(query)))
```

If you beautify the output by

```
cat t2.json | tr  "\'" "\""  | jq '.'
```

You should see something like

```
{
  "in_order": "true",
  "slop": "1",
  "span_near": {
    "clauses": [
      {
        "span_multi": {
          "match": {
            "fuzzy": {
              "msg": {
                "fuzziness": {
                  "fuzziness": "2",
                  "value": "what"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "span_multi": {
          "match": {
            "fuzzy": {
              "msg": {
                "fuzziness": {
                  "fuzziness": "2",
                  "value": "is"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "span_multi": {
          "match": {
            "fuzzy": {
              "msg": {
                "fuzziness": {
                  "fuzziness": "2",
                  "value": "this"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

And then to query ES  it is just a normal

```
curl --silent My_ES_Server:9200:/INDEX/_search -d @t2.json
```

Many thanks for the initial guidance, I hope someone else find this of use.

Comment: How can you make any of the `span_multi` be optional?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, an excellent question and answer.
I'm surprised that this 'fuzzy phrase match' doesn't have support out of the box.

Here's a tested NodeJS code that generates the fuzzy phrase match (multi clause) query block, in the context of a multi search (msearch), but that should work just the same with a single search.

**Usage:**

```js
const queryBody = [
  { index: 'YOUR_INDEX' },
  createESFuzzyPhraseQueryBlock('YOUR PHRASE', 'YOUR_FIELD_NAME', 2)
];

client.msearch({
   body: queryBody
})
```

**Functions**:

```js
const createESFuzzyPhraseClauseBlock = (word, esFieldName, fuzziness) => {
    const clauseBlock = {
            "span_multi": {
                "match": {
                    "fuzzy": {
                        [esFieldName]: {
                            "fuzziness": fuzziness,
                            "value": word
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    return clauseBlock;
};


const createESFuzzyPhraseQueryBlock = (phrase, esFieldName, fuzziness) => {
    const clauses = phrase.split(' ').map(word => createESFuzzyPhraseClauseBlock(word, esFieldName, fuzziness));

    const queryBlock =
        {
            "query":
                {
                    "span_near": {
                        "clauses": clauses,
                        "slop": 1,
                        "in_order": "true"
                    }
                }
        };

    return queryBlock;
};
```

Comment: How can you make any of the `span_multi` be optional?

Answer (score 0):

Consider also mixing the queries, for me basic query looked like this - for phrases of length 2 I've used prefix query and for the rest I've used match query with fuziness set to AUTO.