# Undesired Stopwords in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using Elastic Search 6.This is query

```
PUT /semtesttest
{
    "settings": {
        "index" : {
            "analysis" : {
              "filter": {
                "my_stop": {
                    "type": "stop",
                    "stopwords_path": "analysis1/stopwords.csv"
                  },
                 "synonym" : {
                        "type" : "synonym",
                        "synonyms_path" : "analysis1/synonym.txt"
                    }
                },
                "analyzer" : {
                    "my_analyzer" : {
                        "tokenizer" : "standard",
                        "filter" : ["synonym","my_stop"]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
      "all_questions": {
         "dynamic": "strict",
          "properties": {
            "kbaid":{
              "type": "integer"
            },
            "answer":{
              "type": "text"
            },
            "question":    {
              "type": "text",
              "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
            }
          }
        }
    }
}

PUT /semtesttest/all_questions/1
{
  "question":"this is hippie"
}

GET /semtesttest/all_questions/_search
{
    "query":{
      "fuzzy":{"question":{"value":"hippie","fuzziness":2}}
    }
}

GET /semtesttest/all_questions/_search
{
    "query":{
      "fuzzy":{"question":{"value":"this is","fuzziness":2}}
    }
}
```

in `synonym.txt` it is

```
this, that, money => sainai
```

in `stopwords.csv` it is

```
hello
how
are
you
```

The first get ('hippie') return empty
only the second get ('this is') return results

what is the problem? It looks like the stop word "this is" is filtered in the first query, but I have specified my stop words explicitly?

Answer (score 0):

[fuzzy](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/term-level-queries.html) is a term query.  It is not going to analyze the input, so your query was looking for the exact term `this is` (applying some fuzzy fun).

So you either want to build a query off those two terms, or use a [full text query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/full-text-queries.html) instead.  If fuzziness is important, I think the only full text query is [match](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html):

```
GET /semtesttest/all_questions/_search?pretty 
{
    "query":{
      "match":{"question":{"query":"this is","fuzziness":2}}
    }
}
```

If match phrases is important, you may want to look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38816955/elasticsearch-fuzzy-phrases) and work with [span](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/span-queries.html) queries.

This might also help you so you can see how your analyzer is being used:

```
GET /semtesttest/_analyze?analyzer=my_analyzer&field=question&text=this is
```