# How to combine completion, suggestion and match phrase across multiple text fields?

Tags: elasticsearch

I've been reading about Elasticsearch [suggesters](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters.html#completion-suggester), [match phrase prefix](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase-prefix.html) and [highlighting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-request-highlighting.html) and i'm a bit confused as to which to use to suit my problem.

Requirement: i have a bunch of different *text* fields, and need to be able to autocomplete and autosuggest across all of them, as well as misspelling.  Basically the way Google works.

See in the following Google snapshot, when we start typing "Can", it lists word like Canadian, Canada, etc. This is auto complete. However it lists additional words also like tire, post, post tracking, coronavirus etc. This is auto suggest. It searches for most relevant word in all fields. If we type "canxad" it should also misspel suggest the same results.

[image]

Could someone please give me some hints on how i can implement the above functionality across a bunch of text fields?

At first i tried this:

```
GET /myindex/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase_prefix": {
      "myFieldThatIsCombinedViaCopyTo": "revis"
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "*": {}
    },
    "require_field_match" : false
  }
}
```

but it returns highlights like this:

> "In the aforesaid *revision* filed by the members of the Committee, the present *revisionist* was also party",

So that's not a "prefix" anymore...

Also tried this:

```
GET /myindex/_search
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "revis",
      "fields": ["myFieldThatIsCombinedViaCopyTo"],
      "type": "phrase_prefix",
      "operator": "and"
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "*": {}
    }
  }
}
```

But it still returns

> "In the aforesaid *revision* filed by the members of the Committee, the present *revisionist* was also party",

Note: I have about 5 "text" fields that I need to search upon. One of those fields is quite long (1000s of words). If I break things up into keywords, I lose the phrase. So it's like I need match phrase prefix across a combined text field, with fuzziness?

**EDIT**
Here's an example of a document (some fields taken out, content snipped):

```
{
  "id" : 1,
  "respondent" : "Union of India",
  "caseContent" : "<snip>..against the Union of India, through the ...<snip>"
}
```

As @Vlad suggested, i tried this:

```
POST /cases/_search
POST /cases/_search
{
  "suggest": {
    "respondent-suggest": {
      "prefix": "uni",
      "completion": {
        "field": "respondent.suggest",
        "skip_duplicates": true
      }
    },
    "caseContent-suggest": {
      "prefix": "uni",
      "completion": {
        "field": "caseContent.suggest",
        "skip_duplicates": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Which returns this:

```
{
  "took" : 2,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 0,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "suggest" : {
    "caseContent-suggest" : [
      {
        "text" : "uni",
        "offset" : 0,
        "length" : 3,
        "options" : [ ]
      }
    ],
    "respondent-suggest" : [
      {
        "text" : "uni",
        "offset" : 0,
        "length" : 3,
        "options" : [
          {
            "text" : "Union of India",
            "_index" : "cases",
            "_type" : "_doc",
            "_id" : "dI5hh3IBEqNFLVH6-aB9",
            "_score" : 1.0,
            "_ignored" : [
              "headNote.suggest"
            ],
            "_source" : {
              <snip>
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

So looks like it matches on the `respondent` field, which is great! But, it didn't match on the `caseContent` field, even though the text (see above) includes the phrase "against the Union of India".. shouldn't it match there? or is it because how the text is broken up?

Comment: I think you can go with match phrase prefix I did this in my project for global search in spring boot.

Comment: @DeepDalsania i thought so too, but i don't believe it works on multiple fields in the way i expect. It seemed to be returning words "before" too, e.g when typing "can" it would return "why is canada". not sure if this is because of the tokenization.

Comment: @DeepDalsania updated question.

Comment: If you're using prefix that it always matches all terms which contain you're searched item. To be more specific you can use Multimatch and use type i.e `QueryBuilders.multiMatchQuery(text, fieldNames)
        .type(MultiMatchQueryBuilder.Type.PHRASE_PREFIX)` also you can find any fields like mentioned [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html)

Comment: @DeepDalsania tried that too. still doesn't return prefix. see updated question.

Comment: Ohk, but I got the result in my project where I used, and also there are many types you can try from link I mentioned in the above comment. If nothing is working for you then use Suggestor with your analyzer.

Comment: None of these work because you're using the copy_to field. copy_to is good for searching but not for auto-complete/-suggest because all the text is basically concatenated together and you basically lose the "prefix" of each field. I would definitely use the [completion suggester](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters.html#completion-suggester) for this task. Can you provide a sample document and what result you expect based on a specific search?

Comment: @Val thanks for jumping in. Ok good to know RE copy_to. How can I use completion suggester across multiple fields though? I can provide document and expected result, but I think the screenshot explains it? The document has 8 text fields and I need to autocomplete/suggest across all of them. I'll add document tomorrow though, if it'll help.

Comment: Since you need autocomplete/suggest on each field, then you need to run a suggest query on each field and not on the copy_to field. That way you're guaranteed to have the proper prefixes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you need autocomplete/suggest on each field, then you need to run a suggest query on each field and not on the `copy_to` field. That way you're guaranteed to have the proper prefixes.

`copy_to` fields are great for searching in multiple fields, but not so good for auto-suggest/-complete type of queries.

The idea is that for each of your fields, you should have a `completion` sub-field so that you can get auto-complete results for each of them.

```
PUT index
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "text1": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "suggest": {
            "type": "completion"
          }
        }
      },
      "text2": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "suggest": {
            "type": "completion"
          }
        }
      },
      "text3": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "suggest": {
            "type": "completion"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Your suggest queries would then run on all the sub-fields directly:

```
POST index/_search?pretty
{
    "suggest": {
        "text1-suggest" : {
            "prefix" : "revis", 
            "completion" : { 
                "field" : "text1.suggest" 
            }
        },
        "text2-suggest" : {
            "prefix" : "revis", 
            "completion" : { 
                "field" : "text2.suggest" 
            }
        },
        "text3-suggest" : {
            "prefix" : "revis", 
            "completion" : { 
                "field" : "text3.suggest" 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That takes care of the auto-complete/-suggest part. For misspellings, the suggest queries allow you to specify a [`fuzzy` parameter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters.html#fuzzy) as well

**UPDATE**

If you need to do prefix search on all sentences within a body of text, the approach needs to change a bit.

The new mapping below creates a new completion field next to the text one. The idea is to apply a small transformation (i.e. split sentences) to what you're going to store in the completion field. So first create the index mapping like this:

```
PUT index
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "text1": {
        "type": "text",
      },
      "text1Suggest": {
        "type": "completion"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then create an ingest pipeline that will populate the `text1Suggest` field with sentences from the `text1` field:

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/sentence
{
  "processors": [
    {
      "split": {
        "field": "text1",
        "target_field": "text1Suggest.input",
        "separator": "\\.\\s+"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Then we can index a document such as this one (with only the `text1` field as the completion field will be built dynamically)

```
PUT test/_doc/1?pipeline=sentence
{
  "text1": "The crazy fox. The quick snail. John goes to the beach"
}
```

What gets indexed looks like this (your `text1` field + another completion field optimized for sentence prefix completion):

```
{
  "text1": "The crazy fox. The cat drinks milk. John goes to the beach",
  "text1Suggest": {
    "input": [
      "The crazy fox",
      "The cat drinks milk",
      "John goes to the beach"
    ]
  }
}
```

And finally you can search for prefixes of any sentence, below we search for John and you should get a suggestion:

```
POST test/_search?pretty
{
  "suggest": {
    "text1-suggest": {
      "prefix": "John",
      "completion": {
        "field": "text1Suggest"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Val, I'll try this out today and report back. I thought it'd be more complicated, eg with shingle/ngram analysers (which confuse me), so this is great! One question though, how can I return the most relevant results from all of them, for the user? (see screenshot in question). as I don't actually care which fields it comes from. Would I do an "aggregations" like grouping serverside across all the results?

Comment: see edit with document and what i'm seeing. Your suggestion seems to work for all fields except "caseContent", which is a large text field. So i'm guessing its to do with the mapping/analyzer?

Comment: Yep i see.. it's because of the "prefix". It's only matching the "start" of the text... how can i do if if i want to match any phrase in the caseContent field?

Comment: Glad it's helping! It's not matching caseContent because you insisted on the "prefix" matching and that's what the completion suggester does. But here with "union of india" it seems you need infix, too, i.e. matching inside and not necessarily at the beginning.

Comment: yep - sorry. i meant 'prefix' for the phrases in the content. any ideas how i an do that?

Comment: The way I would go about it is to create a custom analyzer that splits the content into sentences, so that each token of that field is a full sentence, and hence the suggester could prefix-match each sentence.

Comment: Val could you pls point me in the direction of how to do above? Ngram analyser? (sorry, I'm kinda new to this part of ES)

Comment: ok, my bad. What you have is exactly what i asked for, except.. i asked the wrong thing :( I'm sorry! So, my comment "prefix for the phrases in the content" was incorrect. I meant just phrase matching. So given "text1" as you have in your answer, any of the following queries should match: "the cr", "quick sn", "goes to". Is this the "phrase suggester"? (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters.html#phrase-suggester). I tried the example on that docs, but it doesn't seem to be working. So sorry again ..i just haven't explained myself properly :(

Comment: Phrase prefix matching and just phrase matching is quite different, indeed. In that case, we should be looking towards [shingles](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-shingle-tokenfilter.html) and/or the [search-as-you-type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-as-you-type.html) mapping type.

Comment: thanks. I'm going to end up accepting your answer, as I realise I am now "scope creeping" the bounty :)

Comment: One last thing to help me in the right direction, since im newish, which of shingles and/or search as you type is best for my use case? I just want phrase matching in the text, to serve an autocomplete box. Seems search as you type is the best fit?

Comment: Scope has crept a little bit, that's okay, but I think you should create a new question, this one has become crowded already...

Comment: What you need is [`match_phrase_prefix`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase-prefix.html) (i.e. several tokens + the beginning of the last one) but not necessarily from the beginning of the string, but anywhere inside the string. I once had a similar need, so you can check my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30666371/how-to-wisely-combine-shingles-and-edgengram-to-provide-flexible-full-text-searc) and the related answer (especially the part dealing with `substringof`), as it should suit your needs.

Comment: Beware, though, that implementing `substringof` can make your index relatively huge depending on the size of the substrings.

Comment: thanks. yep, i got it working with this answer, since match_phrase doesn't support fuzzy. https://stackoverflow.com/a/38823174/321946

Comment: Cool, glad you figured something out, yet instead of using span queries, I would definitely try to use the newer [`intervals` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-intervals-query.html) which are far more flexible.

Comment: nope, nothing else. thanks again for all your help, you're a star!

Comment: Always glad to help ;-)