# ElasticSearch results are inaccurate

Tags: elasticsearch

My current query is:

```
GET /index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "simple_query_string": {
          "query": "(\"cheaper+than,+therapy\")",
          "analyzer": "standard",
          "flags": "OR|AND",
          "fields": ["name"]
          }
  }
}
```

My main problem is at the moment this still find matches like "GOLF . . . CHEAPER THAN THERAPY". I don't want matches like this. I want to maybe fix some typo and normalize the search query but i don't want to extend them. So in this result the TM's "GOLF . . . CHEAPER THAN THERAPY" and "RUNNING IS: CHEAPER THAN THERAPY" should not be a result.

So the result should just show results which are almost the same as my search query is.

I try something with fuzzienes and so on but it does not help me.
The field `name` is a `text` field.

I await the following results:

- CHEAPER THAN THERAPY
- CHEAPER THAN, THERAPY

I dont await the following results:

- GOLF . . . CHEAPER THAN THERAPY
- "CHEAPER THAN THERAPY" MOORENKO'S
- SHOPPING IS CHEAPER THAN THERAPY!
- RUNNING IS: CHEAPER THAN THERAPY
- CHEAPER THAN THERAPY AND WAY MORE FUN!

What do I have to do to get more accurate results?

Comment: Does this help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38816955/elasticsearch-fuzzy-phrases?

Comment: Can you provide the text which should appear as result

Comment: @TusharShahi is it really so complicated? If yes i need to try it but atm i dont know how to implement this functions.

Comment: @jaspreetchahal sure, thanks good idea i edit my post!

Comment: @Joni yes. If you want exactly those two results it has to be a little complex.

Answer (score 1):

You can use fuzzy query on keyword field.

The standard analyzer is the default analyzer which is used if none is specified. It provides grammar based tokenization. Basically it breaks a text in number of tokens.

So when you are using simple_query_string it is just checking if any document has tokens ["CHEAPER","THAN","THERAPY"] in it.

You can use fuzzy query on text.keyword which will match whole string

```
{
  "query": {
    "fuzzy": {
      "text.keyword": {
        "value": "CHEAPER THAN THERAPY",
        "fuzziness": "AUTO"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Result**

```
[
      {
        "_index" : "index129",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "pnXJM3oBX7bKb5rQ30Vb",
        "_score" : 1.6739764,
        "_source" : {
          "text" : "CHEAPER THAN THERAPY"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index129",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "p3XJM3oBX7bKb5rQ60UT",
        "_score" : 1.5902774,
        "_source" : {
          "text" : "CHEAPER THAN, THERAPY"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: Thanks, is it also possible to use something like querys here? I want to search for more search values at once to save resources. Any idea what i can do here?

Comment: you can combine it using [bool query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html)

Comment: for me it dont return anything. Is it working only with Keyword Fields?

Comment: @Joni Can you add your mapping.  It will work only with non analyzed field. If mapping was not created explicitly then text.keyword will be there

Comment: the field was a text field and i changed it now to keyword field. Your solution is working! But my problem is now it's to slow. I stack arround 1000 search phrases in one request and i guess that will be result the problem. I will send you a email will be nice if you can answer me. Because i guess we run out of topic now :)