# How to use fuzzy and match phrase?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using `elasticsearch` version 7.6.2

I want to search for a sentence and get results of the same words order (like `match_phrase`) with **sentence** `fuzziness`

Example:

```
PUT demo_idx/_doc/1
{
  "content": "michael jordan and scottie pippen"
}
```

I want to search the following sentences (with `fuzziness` equals 2):

- "michael jordan and scottie pippen" -> get results (reason: same sentence)
- "scottie pippen and michael jordan" -> 0 results (reason: words not in the correct order)
- "ichael jordan and scottie pippen" -> get results (reason: 'm' of michael is missing, 1 fuzziness)
- "ichae jordan and scottie pippen" -> get results (reason: 'm' + 'l' of michael are missing, 2 fuzziness)
- "ichael jordan and cottie pippen" -> get results (reason: 'm' of michael and 's' of scottie are missing, 2 fuzziness)
- "ichael jordan and cottie pippe" -> 0 results (reason: 'm' of michael and 's' of scottie and 'n' of pippen are missing, 3 fuzziness)
- "ichael jordan and ottie pippen" -> 0 results (reason: 'm' of michael and 's' + 'c' of scottie are missing, 3 fuzziness)

I read and tried the solution from this post: [Elasticsearch Fuzzy Phrases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38816955/elasticsearch-fuzzy-phrases) but I didn't get the required results.

I have tried:

```
"query": {
            "span_near": {
                "clauses": [
                    {"span_multi":
                     {
                         "match": {
                             "fuzzy": {
                                "content": {
                                    "value": query,
                                    "fuzziness": 2
                                }
                            }
                            }
                     }
                    }
                ],
            }
        }
```

but it didn't worked.

How can I right the search query in order to get the results I want ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have exact matches with fuzziness you can go with keyword tokenizer when defining the index

```
PUT test_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "content": {
      "type":"text",
      "analyzer": "custom_english"
      }
    }
  },
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "custom_english": {
          "tokenizer": "keyword",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ],
          "type":"custom"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can use the fuzzy query to get your search results

```
GET test_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "fuzzy": {
      "content": {
        "value": "ichael jordan and ottie pippen"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is working for all the test cases you mentioned in your question.